# How can i put a variable in string.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, android-xml

I have a variable settings in this way:

```
String result = " Non in carica";
String resultusb = " No";

--
--

if (isCharging) {
 result = " In carica";
} 

if (usbCharge){
 resultusb = " Si";
}
```

The variable `result` or `resultusb` assuming two values depending on the situation..there is no TextView only this, Only one variable with more values. I need translate them so i have to put them in the strings.xml.. How can i do it? How can i translate them?

Comment: Read and learn: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html . The answer here is too short - only one link - so therefore I write a comment.

Comment: How can i consider this? an array?Or quantity?

Comment: There are some already translated strings for you in android.R.string (yes and no is there for example). This does not seem to be an array, but I don't understand your question exactly.

Comment: The result and resultusb could have 2 values.. So in the strings.xml i need for example that charging assuming or In carica or Non in carica.. But it's the same variable. Understand now?

Comment: I think so, yes. I would have two entries in my strings.xml and use an if-else (or more preferably, the ternary operator) to choose which one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this...

In res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="not_charging"> Non in carica</string>
    <string name="is_charging"> In carica</string>
    <string name="usb_no"> No</string>
    <string name="usb_yes"> Si</string>
</resources>
```

And in your code:

```
String result = getString(R.string.not_charging);
String resultusb = getString(R.string.usb_no);

--
--

if (isCharging) {
 result = getString(R.string.is_charging);
} 

if (usbCharge){
 resultusb = getString(R.string.usb_yes);
}
```

Comment: Ummm...isn't that exactly what I said?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the answer is you can't. You can't put them in your `strings.xml` file at runtime. `resources` can't be changed after being compiled.

You can put them in your `strings.xml` file before compiling then retrieve them at runtime with something like

```
if (isCharging) {
   result = getResources().getString(R.String.charging);  // assuming charging is the name in strings.xml
} 

if (usbCharge){
  resultusb = getResources().getString(R.String.si);   // assuming si is the name in strings.xml
 }
```

If this isn't what you are asking for then please be more clear

Comment: The `result` and `resultusb` could have 2 values.. So in the strings.xml i need for example that charging assuming or `In carica` or `Non in carica`.. But it's the same variable. Understand now?

Comment: Maybe. Create 4 variables in `strings.xml`. If `isCharging` then `result = getResources().getString(R.String.inCarica); else result = getResources().getString(R.String.nonCarica);`. Understand?